# drupal breadcrumb experience

Tags: drupal-6

I was wondering what people are using for generating breadcrumbs in drupal.  I've seen various modules and was wondering which ones people have had success with.

Thanks for any thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

Bad news from me: personally I always custom-write breadcrumb code because every professional job I do has different requirements and no generic breadcrumb module can do it all.

I used to create a hook_preprocess_page function then issued my own hook to see if any module would like to rebuild the breadcrumbs - I do it this way so that, for instance, if I have a specialised node I can put the breadcrumb-building code for that node type into its support module (and not try to cram it all into one ever-expanding function - it's the Drupal Way).

Nowadays I use ctools plugins instead of a module hook in the hook_preprocess_page since you can do additional clever stuff.

(If using Panels you'd have to create a new breadcrumb panel pane and work from there. Word to the wise: Panels destroys $_GET['q'] which can make it harder to build breadcrumbs in some situations.)